Why won't a brand new react app won't run in vs code?
This is a brand new react app
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start

That creates a standard react app with structure:
my-app
    --> node_modules
    --> public
    --> src
    ----> App.css
    ----> App.js
    ----> App.test.js
    ----> logo.svg
    ----> reportWebVitals.js
    ----> setupTests.js
    --> package-lock.json
    --> package.json

App.js
    import logo from './logo.svg';
    import './App.css';
    
    function App() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
            <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
            <p>
              Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
            </p>
            <a
              className="App-link"
              href="https://reactjs.org"
              target="_blank"
              rel="noopener noreferrer"
            >
              Learn React
            </a>
          </header>
        </div>
      );
    }

export default App;

index.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint. Learn more: 
reportWebVitals();

package.json
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}

It runs fine from a terminal using npm start but not when clicking the play button.  When clicking the play button I get error:
Could not read source map for chrome-error://chromewebdata/: Unexpected 503 response from chrome-error://chromewebdata/neterror.rollup.js.map: Unsupported protocol "chrome-error:"
I also tried setting the configuration file that VS Code uses to run to Edge Browser:
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "msedge",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Edge against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}

But got the same error.  I want to be able to run from VS Code directly.  Any ideas?

If its brand new and has code and it doesn't work, that is why Stackoverflow exists.  The error points to this file : neterror.rollup.js.map , is there not code in that?

I have no idea where it is.  I shouldn't have to know.  It's a brand new program and VS Code should be able to build and run it.

It should but without knowing what is in that code that is throwing the error, no one will be able to even guess.  But I wonder if you are getting a Chrome error, have you tried other browsers to see if you still get the same error?

FYI - comments are not the place for talking about voting, inability to post, counter-voting, etc. Please keep comments specific to clarification questions.
